# Shipping logic from multiple warehouse in magento1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shipping

I have different warehouses like warehouseA, warehouseB, warehouseC. I purchased one item like product1 as qty 20. This item is available in three warehouses with 10,5,10. This order is check the item is available in warehouseA it decrease the 10 items and remaning in warehouseB, reamining in warehouseC like a below matrix structure.

```
WarehouseName     location      productqty
warehouseA        Bangalore      10
warehouseB        Hyderabad       5
warehouseC        Delhi          10
```

customer purchase the item with Qty 20 to shipping address kolkata. I want the shipping calculation from bangalore->kolkata for 10 items,hyderabad ->kolkata for 5 items and Delhi->kolkata for 5 items?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't support Multiple Warehouses or Stock Locations by default (Even though the database structure is technically there). You will need to install a 3rd party module or write one yourself to provide this functionality.

For example:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=warehouse&pl=0
- https://github.com/DemacMedia/Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory
- http://innoexts.com/promotion/multi-warehouse/

Don't enter into any solution lightly. You're putting the foundation of your business on whichever solution you choose and you need to make sure its throughly tested.

Comment: https://github.com/DemacMedia/Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory --->this extension is only inventory management .its not support the multiple warehouse shipping calculations.we want suggestions for multi warehouse shipping calculations.... plz help me     Thanks,Ram Sampathi

Comment: Have you taken a look at the other modules? What you're wanting to implement is pretty bespoke the innoexts multi-warehouse module may offer the functionality you need, but it may require custom development.